# Why is WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync() faster than WebClient.DownloadString()

Tags: c#, async-await, task

So, I have a loop that is calling an API for about 60 data items. The first implementation of the loop used WebClient.DownloadString() to get the results.

To make the UI responsive during the download I converted the code to use WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync()

```
// Before
string data = webClient.DownloadString(url);

// After
string data = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
```

This did indeed make the UI responsive, but it also reduced the execution time from about 15 seconds down to about 1.6 seconds (a 10X speed increase!)

My question is this: Why? The code is still being executed sequentially and it must wait for one download to complete before the next can begin (albeit without blocking) so how can it execute faster? If anything, I would expect the overhead of the tasks to make it slightly slower.

Comment: the whole execution is on a different thread.

Comment: It isn't. How did you measure performance? The only valid way would be to start a Stopwatch before the call to `DownloadXXX` and check it right afterwards. Most likely you are measuring changes in the rest of your code.

Comment: Please post code that can actually reproduce what you describe

Comment: If you look at the [implementation of the two methods](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,83f74ade9e8b175d) you see they basically do the same things. I would expect the async version to be very slightly slower, albeit more efficient on resources. I think your instrumentation method is flawed.

Comment: To put it another way, the blocking method does *not* add 9x overhead on the actual download. That would be a huge bug of the framework

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I am using Stopwatch but around the whole function call rather than just the download method.

Comment: @Darren so you are measuring your method, not the download. Post the rest of the code, *that's* what's going 10x faster, not the download. If you want to measure the download, collect times for it *only* and save/log them somewhere. You'll see they haven't really changed

Comment: I actually quite sure the async methods are even slower that the synchronized one. the program has to more in order to not block the CPU and jump in and out of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason. The developer (me) is an idiot.

Sorry to have wasted your time on this one. When I started stripping down the before and after code to post as a sample I found a `Thread.Sleep()` in the before code that was there for testing purposes.

With the `Thread.Sleep()` removed the times are both in the same ball park.

+1 to everyone who posted a helpful comment

Comment: This answer doesn't help anyone, you should probably just delete the question as technically it should now be closed as a typo.

Answer (score -1):

It is nothing extraordinary the differences of speed, if you look good in the implementation of both do almost the same, the difference between them is when to use it. For example the async method is more efficient when you use them on mobile devices for example. Check out async on MSDN for more information.

Comment: Async methods are not peculiar to mobile devices and can be applied anywhere

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model